# Play every hand or not

Tags: tournament, soft-question

in a tournament where the level increases approximately every 5 minutes, do i have more chances winning by:

- playing as many hands as possible, and fold after the flop if I have nothing
- calling just the hands where i get high cards initially, like AA, KK etc. So basically folding all crap hands before the flop

Comment: If you play every hand and fold to flops you don't like, you will become highly exploitable.

Answer (score 5):

If you had more chance to win by playing every hand, everyone would play every hand all the time and there wouldn't be much of a game.